# What wallets are available for the EOS coin?

Tags: tokens, wallet

To be clear, I'm not talking about the EOS erc20 token, I'm talking about the coin post-launch. I haven't heard mention of any wallets, 3rd party or otherwise that will be ready on launch day. Are there any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer probably will change over time, but you should be able to find a list of wallets on:

https://eosprojects.org/categories/wallet/

Currently listed are:

- http://scatter-eos.com/
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.mithrilcoin.eoscommander
- https://github.com/PearlWallet/Pearl

// disclaimer: I am creator of eosprojects

Answer (score 7):

An EOS wallet is in the making by 3rd party developers recognized by Block.one. You can find details about 'EOSWallet' under EOS Essentials here https://github.com/EOSEssentials.

Answer (score 3):

Among other things EOS.CYBEX claims they will launch the world's first hardware cold wallet for EOS. 
They state on their home page, [linked](https://eos.cybex.io/), that "transactions happening on EOS are rather big in data volume, which will translate into a problem in embedded devices like hardware wallet, for the length of signature accounts hugely for hardware storage capacity." 
So I am guessing hardware wallets like the Trezor and Nano S may have difficulty implementing EOS.

Answer (score 0):

that's a good question actually. We're building a wallet right into our product (Carmel.io) to make it easier for our community to purchase Carmel Tokens right from within the product. We realized it would probably help the community a lot if we actually allowed our in-app wallet to support any other EOS token, other than our own Carmel Token. So we will do that. Stay tuned for updates on that. BTW, the code is all open source so anyone is welcome to pitch in and contribute (http://github.com/fluidtrends/carmel)